# Actioncable channel can't receive my params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

I am creating a rails messenger.
But it seem that i can't find the subscribed room with params.
if I hard code the params it works but i can only send messages in the first room

```
class PostChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
 def subscribed

   post = Post.first
   stream_for post
 end
```

the outcome:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-06-29 17:08:01 +0200
   (0.3ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-06-29 17:08:01 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/channels/post_channel.rb:10:in `subscribed'
PostChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
PostChannel is streaming from post:Z2lkOi8vb2Rpbi1hY3Rpb24tY2FibGUvUG9zdC8x
```

now i want to have the id post so i can send messages in the good room.
here is my code and what i tried:

post_channel.rb

```
class PostChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed

    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    stream_for post
  end
```

post_channel.js
here i try to turbolink my actioncable so it triggers only in a post#show so i can have the podt id in the params

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
  var body = document.getElementById("room-messages");
  if(body) {
    consumer.subscriptions.create({channel: 'PostChannel', 
    post: $('#room_messages').attr('data-room')
    }, {
      connected() {
        console.log("Connected")
      },

      disconnected() {
        console.log("disconnected")
      },

      received(data) {
        console.log("data receiveid:");
        console.log(data);
        //Output:
        //Object { id: 6, content: "Test Log", user_id: 1, post_id: 1, created_at: "2021-06-15T07:45:53.068Z", updated_at: "2021-06-15T07:45:53.068Z" }
        $('#display').append('<p> ' + data.user_id + '</p>')
        $('#display').append('<p> ' + data.content + '</p>')
        
      }
    });
  }
});
```

show.html.erb
here i receive messages

```
<div 
  class="container"
  id="room-messages"
  data-channel-subscribe="post"
  data-room ="<%= @post.id %>"
>
...
  <div class="message">
    <h3>Messages:</h3>
    
    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <p class="userMessage"><%=message.user_id%></p>
      <p class="content"><%= message.content %></p>
    <% end %>
    <div id="display"></div>
    <%= render "message/form", message: @message %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the messages error I've got:

```
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-06-29 17:03:14 +0200
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Could not execute command from ({"command"=>"subscribe", "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"PostChannel\"}"}) [ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Post without an ID]: /home/nigaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:431:in `find_with_ids' | /home/nigaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:69:in `find' | /home/nigaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:21:in `find' | /home/nigaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.7/lib/active_record/core.rb:167:in `find' | /home/nigaz/railsWork/LearnActionCable/OdinActionCable/app/channels/post_channel.rb:9:in `subscribed'
```

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: try change `post: $('#room_messages').attr('data-room')` to `id: $('#room_messages').attr('data-room')`

Comment: i did, but nothing change. i try to use `stream from` but the output show me that it can't find data-room in my show.html.erb